# create a table dynamically based on sql result

Tags: php, image, mysqli

i have been trying to work out a problem i have for some time now with no luck...

i have a sql table (`$photos`) to which i need to make a html table to place these in, however the table can only be 4 rows wide i.e.

```
-----------------------------------------
| image 1 | image 2 | image 3 | image 4 |
-----------------------------------------
| image 5 | image 6 | image 7 | image 8 |
-----------------------------------------
```

etc

i have the sql result set and the column names are as follows `$photo_id` -> primary key `$linkUri` -> location of image based on page (i.e. /images/image1.gif)

can someone give me some pointers or an example of how to do this?

would using limit work?

any help would be more than helpful :)

Answer (score -1):

You can easily set a break-point for your table based on the number of results by using the **modulus** operator. You would basically check if the key you're currently at *divided* by the column width is equal to 0, then end the current table row and start a new one.

The tricky bit is managing what happens in the event that you have 9 elements, and you're displaying 4 on every row - in the case, the last table row needs to be padded with empty data so that your markup is still valid. In any sense, I've written a small piece of useful, but spaghetti code which will get you started. Just add the following to your view and replace variables as needed.

```
<?php $columnWidth = 4;?>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

        <?php foreach ($images as $key => $image):?>
            <?php if ($key % $columnWidth === 0 && $key !== 0):?>
                </tr><tr>
            <?php endif;?>

            <td><?php echo img($image->linkUri);?></td>
        <?php endforeach;?>

        <?php
            $elementsStillLeftToPad = $columnWidth - 1 - ($key % $columnWidth);

            if ($elementsStillLeftToPad !== 0) {
                for ($element = 0; $element < $elementsStillLeftToPad; $element++):?>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <?php endfor;
            }
        ?>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You may consider moving the code above into a helper, since that way, it's cleaner and more DRY. You may also consider using a templating engine which would ease this task a lot.

Comment: Thanks Petre, i will try this when i get back home =]